# How to do insert with an exported file

Tags: mysql

I have the below code exported into a sql file.

```
        INSERT INTO `MyGuests` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES
('1', 'John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com', '2017-06-04 18:39:29'),
('2', 'Bill', 'Doe', 'bill@example.com', '2017-06-04 18:42:31'),
('3', 'Jane', 'Doe', 'jane@example.com', '2017-06-04 18:42:31');
```

I want to import it into another data base with same schema but i want it to autoincrement and put the next incremental id in place... can I do this as below just remove the `id` and sequential nr before importing.?

```
                INSERT INTO `HisGuests` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES
('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com', '2017-06-04 18:39:29'),
('Bill', 'Doe', 'bill@example.com', '2017-06-04 18:42:31'),
('Jane', 'Doe', 'jane@example.com', '2017-06-04 18:42:31');
```

Or do i need something like this..

```
                INSERT INTO `HisGuests` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES
('', 'John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com', '2017-06-04 18:39:29'),
('', 'Bill', 'Doe', 'bill@example.com', '2017-06-04 18:42:31'),
('', 'Jane', 'Doe', 'jane@example.com', '2017-06-04 18:42:31');
```

I also changed the db name to indicate the new db plus the new db will already have some data so its important that it pickup the next id and continue from that point.. forward.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Use first variant:

```
INSERT INTO `HisGuests` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES
('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com', '2017-06-04 18:39:29'),
('Bill', 'Doe', 'bill@example.com', '2017-06-04 18:42:31'),
('Jane', 'Doe', 'jane@example.com', '2017-06-04 18:42:31');
```

Without `id` field, MySQL will auto increment it.

Comment: As you can see i did exactly that in the center example and it did not work.. maybe i did not have the autoincrement set to on... not sure..will check on that..